помогите с домашним заданием (9 класс) можно использовать def for while if elif else ну базу базу крч

Представьте себя космическим рейнджером. Создайте функцию, имеющую в себе расстояния от Земли до пяти ближайших звезд (расстояния и названия звезд найдите в интернете). Пользователь вводит скорость своего корабля и получает время (в часах), за которое он доберется до каждой звезды. Если на путешествие будет тратиться более 10 лет, выведите на экран рекомендацию поработать над кораблем и скорость, которая нужна, чтобы путешествие длилось менее 10 лет.

Представьте себя космическим рейнджером. Создайте функцию, имеющую в себе расстояния от Земли до пяти ближайших звезд (расстояния и названия звезд найдите в интернете). Пользователь вводит скорость своего корабля и получает время (в часах), за которое он доберется до каждой звезды. Если на путешествие будет тратиться более 10 лет, выведите на экран рекомендацию поработать над кораблем и скорость, которая нужна, чтобы путешествие длилось менее 10 лет.
def cosmos (scor): 
time = 0

merkuriy = 82/scor
venera = 62/scor
mars = 55 /scor``
upiter = 588/scor
saturn = 1200/scor
if merkuriy >= 10:
    
    i = 0
    while merkuriy1 <10:
        merkuriy1/=1.1
        i+=1
    print(merkuriy1)     
            
    print('для того чтобы достигнуть меркурий потребуется ' ,merkuriy, ' световых лет, улучшите скорость корабля примерно на ', i)
print(venera)
print(mars)
print(upiter)
print(saturn)

merkuriy = 82

merkuriy1 = merkuriyyour text

venera = 62 mars = 55 upiter = 588 saturn = 1200 cosmos (int(input('введите скорость в световых годах\n')))


Что не так с приведённым кодом?

нет, я хотел чтобы мне помогли его доделать до условия, я просто гуманитарий

Раз гуманитарий, то перефразируйте с гуманитарного на технический, что надо сделать(подготовьте внятное ТЗ). Опишите, что смогли сделать вы вашим кодом и что из вашего ТЗ у вас не получилось реализовать.

Настолько "гуманитарий", что не различаете планеты (Меркурий, Венера, Марс и т.д.) и звёзды, указанные в вопросе?  Расстояние от Земли до соседних планет -- десятки световых лет??

def cosmos(speed: float) -> float:
    # расстояние в световых годах
    stars = {
        "Проксима_Центавра": 4.24,
        "Альфа_Центавра": 4.37,
        "Барнардова_звезда": 5.96,
        "Вольф_359": 7.78,
        "Лаланде_21185": 8.29,
    }
    for star in stars.keys():
        path = stars[star]
        time = path / speed
        if time > 10:
            print(f"Нужно поработать над кораблём и скоростью, чтобы добраться до {star}.")
        else:
            print(f"Чтобы добраться до {star} нужно {round(time, 2)} лет.")


def main():
    speed = float(input("Введите скорость в световых годах: "))
    cosmos(speed)


main()


Скорость не измеряется в световых годах. Выводить при неудаче ещё кое-что нужно.

@MBo, в ТЗ ничего про другие рекомендации не было, а измерение скорости в световых годах, можно увидеть в коде автора. Мы тут не физики, понятно, что в рамках задания это совершенно не важно.

@Runneso чисто логически: это как если бы мы использовали не скорость автомобиля, а расстояние которое он проехал за год
